# How to capture columns from joined tables using output clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am updating a table called tableA by joining tableB and tableC at the same time I am capturing updated records into temp table using output clause from tableA . Now I want capture columns from table B for the updated data but output clause isn't allowing the same.

Eg:

```
Update SLC Set SLC.Datascrublevel =  C.Datascrublevel
        OUTPUT [Deleted].Systemcode,                
       [Deleted].Systemkey,
       [Deleted].datascrublevel,
        [Inserted].datascrublevel 
       INTO #TEMP1                      
       FROM TABLEA SLC with(nolock)                
    INNER JOIN TABLEB SC ON SC.SystemCode = SLC.SystemCode  
    INNER JOIN TABLEC SL ON SL.SystemCode = SLC.SystemCode and SLC.SystemKey = SL.Systemkey                 
    INNER JOIN #TEMP C ON                   SLC.Datascrublevel <> C.DataScrubLevel AND C.Systemcode = SLC.SystemCode and C.Systemkey = SLC.SystemKey
```

Now I want columns from tableB to capture into temp table using output clause. Please provide your advise if there are any alternative ways.

Comment: Nolock - really? You're updating SLC (TABLEA) so using the nolock hint is pointless. More importantly, it is both ignored and deprecated In fact, just forget that hint exists since it isn't a magic, consequence-free, "go faster" option.

Answer (score 1):

Just Like you have given it as `[deleted].[Column Name]` and `[Inserted].[Column Name]` add one more column as `[SC].[Column Name]`

Example :

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDb..#TABLEA') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TABLEA

IF OBJECT_ID('TempDb..#TABLEB') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TABLEB

IF OBJECT_ID('TempDb..#TABLEC') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TABLEC

IF OBJECT_ID('TempDb..#TABLED') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TABLED


CREATE TABLE #TABLEA
(
    SeqNo INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    MyDate DATE
)

CREATE TABLE #TABLEB
(
    SeqNo INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    FullName VARCHAR(20)
)

CREATE TABLE #TABLEC
(
    SeqNo INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    FullName VARCHAR(20),
    MyDate DATE
)

CREATE TABLE #TABLED
(
    SeqNo INT,
    MyDate DATE,
    FullName VARCHAR(20)    
)

INSERT INTO #TABLEA
(
    MyDate
)
SELECT GETDATE()
UNION
SELECT GETDATE()+1
UNION
SELECT GETDATE()-1

INSERT INTO #TABLEB
(
    FullName
)
VALUES('A'),('B'),('C')

INSERT INTO #TABLEC
(
    FullName
)
VALUES('A'),('B'),('C')

UPDATE C
    SET MyDate = A.MyDate
    OUTPUT
    deleted.SeqNo,
    deleted.MyDate,
    B.FullName
    INTO #TABLED
    FROM #TABLEC C
        INNER JOIN #TABLEB B
            ON C.FullName = B.FullName
        INNER JOIN #TABLEA A
            ON A.SeqNo = B.SeqNo

SELECT * FROM #TABLED
```